# PHP concatenate variable

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

Might be an easy question for you guys. can't find it on google.

I am trying to concatenate two variables name;

```
$i=0;
 for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   if($array[$i]>0){

   $test.$i=//do something
   }else{
  $test.$i=//do something
  }
}

//echo $test0 gives me nothing.
//echo $test1 gives me nothing.
```

I know I can't use $test.$i but don't know how to do this.Any helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try `${$test.$i} = value`

EDIT: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Accepted answer because of the link! :D

Comment: The last two lines of the OP's code imply that if $i == 0, he's trying to access $test0. In this case, if $test is undefined, then $test will evaluate to the empty string and {$test.$i} will evaluate to "0".

Comment: I think, you have click below the score on the check to accept the answer ;)

Comment: I can't. there is a message pop up saying I have to wait for 3 min.

Comment: ahhh..:D ... didn't know, sorry

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that the variables are called $test0, $test1, ..., $test5. You can use the following:

```
${"test".$i}
```

Though, might I suggest that you make $test an array and use $i as the index instead? It's very odd to use $i as an index to loop through a list of variable names.

As an example, instead of:

```
$test0 = "hello";
$test1 = "world";
```

Use:

```
$test[0] = "hello";
$test[1] = "world";
```

Comment: I do like your suggestion. I already gave the accepted answer to Simon. +1 though :D

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $the_test = $test.$i;
    if($array[$i]>0){
        $$the_test=//do something
    }
    else{
        $$the_test=//do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
$varName = $test . $i;
$$varName = ...
```

Can i ask where for this is neccesary?

Comment: I am trying to loop a two dimension arrays..its hard to explain here, but I need concatenation to get what I need. Thanks though. +1